# Buttons in list item overflows when using item-button-right

Tags: android, html, ionic-framework

I have three buttons in each list item, I want to display them next to each other on the right hand side, but if I add `"item item-button-right"` the items moves right but overflows with each other and then it looks like one button. I have tried `<ul></ul>` but then the buttons are beneath the item text.

```
html
         <ion-list>
                    <ion-item class="item item-button-right">
                        Make and Model:
                        <ul>
                        <button class="button button-positive">
                            <i class="icon ion-checkmark-round"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="button button-positive">
                            <i class="icon ion-close-round"></i>
                        </button>
                        <button class="button button-positive">
                            <i class="icon ion-ios-camera"></i>
                        </button>
                        </ul>
                    </ion-item>
                    <ion-item class="item-positive" href="#/app/checklist">
                         Next
                    </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXZJqZ) to demostrate one solution through CSS.

The relevant added CSS:

```
.item.moreButtons button { margin-top: -5px; } /* first */
.item.moreButtons button:nth-child(2) { margin-top: 35px; } /* second */
.item.moreButtons button:last-child { margin-top: 75px; } /* thrid */
```

Also don't forget to set the class on the `<ion-item>` element, like this:

```
<ion-item class="item item-button-right moreButtons">
```

Comment: And if they need to be next to each other instead of stacked, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372444/how-can-i-show-two-icons-as-right-aligned-within-an-ionic-list